# Git flow - managing differences between master and develop

Tags: git, workflow, rebase, git-flow

I've been using Git Flow for a little while now, however in the initial week or so I was creating release branches manually from master and cherry picking the required commits into the release branch rather than creating them from master.

For example, if I have commit `abcd123 My commit message` in the develop branch, I had also cherry picked it into the release branch manually, and at this point I had probably amended or edited the commit message, so the release branch (and now master branch) contain this commit but with a different hash, e.g. `dbca321 My adjusted commit message`.

The problem here is that when I create the release from develop, it also contains commits that I don't want to deploy at this stage, so I rebase against master and exclude the commits I don't want. After rebasing however, the commit hash is different for "My commit message" above between master, the release and develop. This probably explains why it keeps showing up whenever I create a release.

I want to be able to use Git Flow to create releases from develop, but remove certain commits where necessary without having this issue occur. Creating the release branches manually via cherry picking is an easy way to achieve that, and when it is back merged to develop it seems to work nicely, however it's not how Git Flow is supposed to be used.

How do I get Git Flow (master/develop) back on track/in sync and achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using gitflow for a while. Here's my practice for it:

1. Everything goes into `develop` until you feel you are ready to start preparing the release. This may be any timeframe between minutes and days from the last deployment.
2. Create a `release` branch off of `develop`, or better yet - off of the last commit on the develop branch that should really go into the release. The idea is to minimise the cherry-picks or reverts between `develop` and `release`, as they cause headaches.
3. Keep committing into `release`, unless you are adding/changing something that cannot go into the release branch. In this case, commit to `develop`, but again try to minimise to reduce the merge headache.
4. When ready, merge the release branch into `develop` and `master`, test and deploy.
5. Go back to 1.

Some GUI tools wrap git nicely and offer one-click gitflow actions, but you should always strive to know what happens under the hood to troubleshoot these 'automatic' tools when they fail.

Comment: Hey Anton, thanks for the answer. Can you explain a little more about how you would exclude certain commits from develop once you've created a release from it that contains commits you don't want to deploy? Do you revert them, rebase them out, etc?

Comment: Not speaking out of experience here, but I would branch off to the release branch when no commits have to be reverted, and then cherry-pick newer commits from develop into the release branch. This way, when the release is ready, merging it back to develop and master keeps everything in sync. If you revert commits on the release branch, you mess up the merge-back into develop and master.