# git only merge specific feature from dev to master

Tags: git

I have a master (production) and a staging branch. When I start a new feature I add a new branch based on staging.
This feature branch then gets merged back to staging and deployed to a staging environment (web server)

Let's assume there are 5 new features merged to the staging branch and the feature branches are deleted. QA approves 3 of the features for production.
Normally I would merge staging to master, but how can I selectively merge features to production and exclude others when I merge staging?

Comment: It's not an answer, but I would like to say that you should not merge to master directly as you don't have tested on your web server the 3 features only. There might be some bugs without the 2 features that have not be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) specific commits into your branch:

```
git checkout master
git log staging
# Identify which commits you want to bring over
git cherry-pick COMMITHASH
```

Comment: @RomainValeri sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @RomainValeri commit hashs are not specific to branches

Comment: Ha, I took it backwards, OP wants to cherry-pick from feature to master, not the reverse, and you logged staging, sorry for the noise ^^

Comment: @RobbieAverill I have thought about cherry pick, but won't this cause problems when I eventually merge staging into master?

Comment: @Chris it may do. Git is pretty smart about automatically merging things for you, but the commit hashes do change when you cherry-pick a commit. I actually asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981834/git-flow-managing-differences-between-master-and-develop) to this a while ago